# HTML5 Canvas Size to Span the whole html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently learnt JavaScript and decided to go ahead and implement a page for Github. Everything looks fine but the only problem I face is that the JS code for canvas doesn't scale the full html page, meaning the particles bounce off from the initial window and when I scroll down, that space remains devoid of any particles. I want the JS canvas to have particles all over the page. Can someone help me as to how I can go about fixing it?

TLDR: How can I fix the JS code so that the particle effect span the whole html page rather than just the initial window leaving everything else devoid?

https://devkapupara.github.io/
Relevant file: https://github.com/devkapupara/devkapupara.github.io

Comment: Oh well :/ Different devices might have different configs. I am viewing it from my phone and looks exactly the same.

Comment: Now that the effect scales full screen it's not that bad :D but who am i to judge? I'm just some random guy on internet

Comment: Every opinion counts :)

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve] in the question itself, [here on Stack Overflow](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an html/css issue, not a js issue. Even if you assign your element 100% width, the body of your template may have built in padding. Try the following:

```
<!-- HTML -->

<div id="my-canvas-container">
  <!-- this is where your canvas would load -->
</div>



/* CSS */

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#my-canvas-container {
  min-width:100%
}
```

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. I suppose if I fix the position and make the display block, everything could be on one page itself.

Comment: Just edited my answer to say "padding" not "passing" haha. I do believe that most mobile apps are designed as "single page" when they are just starting out.